# Understanding Borg Singleton Pattern in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, design-patterns

I saw this Borg Singleton Pattern code but I couldn't get my head around how  new members I add to the singleton object gets appended to the `__shared_state = {}` dictionary.

Here is the Singleton code

```
class Borg(object):
    _shared_state = {}

    def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        obj = super(Borg,cls).__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
        obj.__dict__ = cls._shared_state
        return obj

class Child(Borg):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    borg = Borg()
    another_borg = Borg()

    print borg is another_borg
    child = Child()

    borg.only_one_var = "I'm the only one var"    
    print child.only_one_var
```

So my question when the object `borg.only_one_var` is created how does it get appended to `_shared_state` dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default each instance gets its own dictionary and hence assigning an attribute to one instance doesn't affect other instances.

But you can make an instance's dictionary to point to a new dict and when you do so internally it will be used from there on to store items.

In your case every time an instance is being created you're assigning its dictionary to point to a `Borg. _shared_state`. Hence, all its instances will use the same dict to fetch and set attributes.

It's basically equivalent to:

```
shared = {}

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = shared
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> ins = [A() for _ in range(5)]
>>> ins[0].x = 100
>>> for i in ins:
...     print(i.x)
...
100
100
100
100
100

>>> shared
{'x': 100}
```

In CPython the assignment of new dictionary to `__dict__` happens inside [`PyObject_GenericSetDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L1286):

```
int
PyObject_GenericSetDict(PyObject *obj, PyObject *value, void *context)
{
    PyObject **dictptr = _PyObject_GetDictPtr(obj);
    ...
    if (!PyDict_Check(value)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "__dict__ must be set to a dictionary, "
                     "not a '%.200s'", Py_TYPE(value)->tp_name);
        return -1;
    }
    Py_INCREF(value);
    Py_XSETREF(*dictptr, value);  # Set the dict to point to new dict
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that since the arrival of [key-sharing dictionaries](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/) in Python 3.3+ the dictionaries of instances of same class can share some internal state to save space.

Comment: Any idea why they are incrementing the address of `value` ? Specifically, this statement `Py_INCREF(value);`.

Comment: @RuthvikVaila `Py_INCREF` is used for increasing the reference count of an object. CPython uses reference count as a way to garbage-collect objects.

Answer (score 1):

In the simple case of an out of class context dictionary, as you probably know, you can append new key-value pairs like:

```
dic = {}
dic['first'] = 1
print(dic)
>>> {'first': 1}
```

In your case, you assigned the `_shared_state` dictionary to the object's dictionary `obj.__dict__`. so now the `obj.__dict__` is a reference to that `_shared_state` dictionary.

When you use that dot-path notation on the `obj` instance you actually append a key-value pair to it's dictionary, and therefor to the `_shared_state` dictionary.

Since this class is a singleton, all other instances' dictionaries will refer to that same `_shared_state` dictionary. therefor all of the instances will have the "same" `__dict__`.

Comment: Doesn't work. `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'dict'`

Comment: Thank you. Writing about dictionaries and thinking about objects. Silly me :)